# How to see a Java Blueprint in Apache Brooklyn

Tags: brooklyn

I followed the steps of the following example:

https://brooklyn.incubator.apache.org/v/0.7.0-SNAPSHOT/java/archetype.html

And now I have my jar into the /target directory (I assume that this is the java blueprint).

What I want is to see that blueprint in the apache brooklyn server, but I can not see nothing.

I copied the generated jar in lib/brooklyn and in lib/dropins but without success when I start the server. I can not see nothing when I start the server.

Am I missing something? Could it be some problem with versions? The generation on the jar was made with the Milestone 1 and the apache brooklyn is the 0.7.0-Snapshot of May

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Presence of the jar in `lib/dropins` makes your blueprint usable via YAML blueprints or via other Java blueprints.

For example if your Java blueprint is called `com.acme.brooklyn.MyBlueprint`, then you could launch a YAML app such as:

```
location: localhost
services:
- type: com.acme.brooklyn.MyBlueprint
```

If you want your blueprint to be listed in the catalog (i.e. be discoverable), you have a few options (in latest 0.7.0-snaphshot):

- You can post to the REST api to add it (see https://brooklyn.incubator.apache.org/v/latest/ops/catalog/index.html)
- You can add to the catalog via the CLI (see "CLI Options" in https://github.com/apache/incubator-brooklyn/blob/master/docs/guide/ops/catalog/index.md)
- You can configure Brooklyn to do classpath scanning, to find all annotated blueprints (see use of `scanJavaAnnotations`, in the above link)

You could also consider building your code as an OSGi bundle, rather than putting it in lib/dropins. The advantage of using OSGi is that you can have versioned Java blueprints, updating the code for different versions.